# Should I use DoctrineBundle alongside with DoctrineMongoDBBundle?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I am using MongoDB as a DB storage, thus I should use `DoctrineMongoDBBundle` to use Doctrine in my `Symfony` application. `DoctrineBundle` is installed by default with new `Symfony` installation, but I can safety remove it and it seems not to affect my work with Doctrine.

Should I really remove this bundle? Is it completely useless in case of using MongoDB, or I miss something, and I will need this bundle for some reason in the future?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

*Doctrine* can mean a few things. Usually it's by default understood as Doctrine ORM. But in your case you want to use Doctrine MongoDB ODM.

`DoctrineBundle` is a Symfony intergration for **Doctrine ORM and DBAL**

`DoctrineMongoDBBundle` is a Symfony integration for **Doctrine MongoDB ODM**

Doctrine ORM and Doctrine MongoDB ODM are two separate, independent projects.

Therefore you can remove DoctrineBundle if you don't use relational databases.